# How to use clippath to overlay an image in a rect in SVG?

Tags: svg

I am trying to overlay an image in a rectangle in SVG but I can't seem to get it work.

Essentially I have a larger image that I need to fit into a smaller `rect` but how do I do this properly?

This is my code:

```html
   <svg width="665" height="455" viewBox="0 0 665 455" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clipme">
                <rect x="286" y="268" width="310" height="107" rx="10" />
            </clipPath>  
        </defs>
        
        <rect x="286" y="200" width="205" height="6" rx="3" fill="#aaa"/>
        <rect x="286" y="220" width="310" height="4" rx="2" fill="#E5D0FF"/>
        <rect x="286" y="230" width="297" height="4" rx="2" fill="#E5D0FF"/>
        <rect x="286" y="240" width="271" height="4" rx="2" fill="#E5D0FF"/>
        <rect x="286" y="250" width="239" height="4" rx="2" fill="#E5D0FF"/>
      
        <rect x="286" y="268" width="310" height="107" rx="10" fill="#F7F4FB"/>
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJkK0.jpg" width="600" height="200" clip-path="url(#clipme)"  />
    
    </svg>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pdu4mrho/

**This is what I get:**
[image: current output]

**This is the desired output:**
[image: desired output]

Comment: Your image needs an x and y attributes. Please try   x="200" y="200". In order to understand what happens remove the clip-path attribute of the image. You will see that the image stands far away from the clipping rect.

Comment: I see - thank you!. Solved with `<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJkK0.jpg" width="320" height="117" x="286" y="268" clip-path="url(#clipme)" />`. Please post an answer and I will award.